# Enable automatic line-breaking for SVG output

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

The MathJax configuration for the HTML–CSS output processor includes the option `linebreaks: { automatic:true }`. When using this output processor (right-click on any MathJax formula → Math Settings → Math Renderer → HTML-CSS), long display-style formulas look like this:

[image]

However, this option is not set for the SVG output processor. When using this output processor (right-click on any MathJax formula → Math Settings → Math Renderer → SVG), long display-style formulas look like this:

[image]

Could we please configure the SVG output processor to include the `linebreaks: { automatic:true }` option?

See also: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-line-breaking

Comment: It's also missing for the CommonHTML output.